# Is it safer to install two OSes on different hard drives or just different partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

If I dual boot install both Ubuntu and Windows, is it safer to install them on two different hard drives than different partitions on the same hard drive?

What risks may be involved? For example, one OS does not recognize the files of another OS. One OS accidentally wipes out the other OS by some system operations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, they should leave each other alone. If you do the install correctly (Windows first, then Linux, as a rule, because Linux is more 'considerate'). As far as I am aware, there is no additional risk involved in sharing a drive.

Having said that, here are some gotchas to watch out for.

1. Windows will not be able to see the contents of your Linux drive or partition, unless you install additional software. [ext4fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) works for me.
2. Shared storage partitions. If there is a partition which both OSes can see *natively*, meaning [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) or [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), then there can be issues with data loss. If Windows goes into hibernation, and another OS makes changes to the shared partition, Windows will tend to undo the changes when it is resumed. I recommend either external storage, or disabling hibernation on Windows, or both.
3. [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface). This is new with Windows 8. There are two types of firmware interface, [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) (older) and UEFI (newer). Both operating systems need to be installed using the same one. You can find a much more in-depth explanation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Comment: On Windows, to disable hibernation, simply run ,from the console (as Administrator), the following command: `powercfg -h off`.

Comment: _ext4fsd_ should read _ext2fsd_. As it doesn't fully support `ext4`, I would always use _ext2fsd_ in read-only mode to prevent accidental corruption.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand no 2. what do you mean by `hibernation` ? can you explain a bit more thoroughly please?

Comment: Hibernation is a method of shutting a computer down while saving its state, so like a hybrid between conventional shutdown and suspend - it's a state which Windows enters automatically under certain circumstances. For more information, please read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 13):

It is safer to use 2 hard disks.

1. during formatting it is easier to recognize the different hard disks. 1 will be named sda and the other sdb. Though the installer puts names next to bootable partitions it does help to find other partitions that belong to that specific OS (like a D: drive will be sda2 on sda where sda1 is the OS for Windows or db2 is a partition for sdb where sdb1 is the root for Ubuntu).
2. hard drive failure. Does one drive fail you take it out and still boot into the other OS (maybe with the help of GRUB recovery).

I myself though would install the bootable partitions (ie. the operating system (C: and /)) on the fastest hard drive and put my data on the other drive.

But... backups and being able to restore them is more important. The best thing to do is make regular backups of your important data. If you do that you will only have minor problems.

Comment: Thanks. Does what you say about fast and slow hard drives applies to an internal hard drive and an external hard drive?

Comment: 1. It is problem with user's perception and focus, not with the partitions setup.
2. Every disk can fail, separate disk too. Right, with two disks setup we would loss only one OS in case of one disk failure, but it doesn't matter. Users' data matters, not OSes.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki I agree :D Backups and being able to restore them is more important.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki: Agree user data matters. So better to store OSes and data on different hard drives? If my laptop has only one internal hard drive and I have an external hard drive, what do you suggest?

Comment: Keep the data on the internal AND the external drive (you could use a synch tool to to that).

Comment: With 2 drives (of similar speed), you should put Linux `/` on a RAID1 of a partition from each drive.  Keep big data files somewhere else, if you don't want to take up space storing them twice.  RAID1 isn't a substitute for backups, though, since it doesn't protect against accidental or malicious deletion.

Comment: But I will agree that having Windows in full control of the bootloader on its own drive is a moderate advantage if you ever re-install windows, instead of being careful to avoid malware so you don't have to.  It can be a pain to fix your boot setup, esp. if you aren't an expert with GRUB and whatever the hell Windows needs to boot correctly.

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer:**

It doesn't matter at all.

**Detailed answer:**

There is absolutely no risk with keeping two operating systems on the same disk device. You can mess with another system partition as long as the disk device with that partition is accesible, putting it on separate physical device doesn't make it safer (nor less safe) in any way.

Comment: I think this answer should read: Once the installation for both OS'es has succeeded, there is no risk. There are a lot of questions on these forums, SuperUser and Linux SE on what to do because the user has lost boot access to an OS after an improper installation.

Comment: @PeterMortensen With two disks setup, one OS can overwrite bootloader used by the other OS as well. Second disk doesn't prevent such scenario in any way.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu please give a link to description of problem that is caused directly by placing two OSes on one disk and will never occur when each OS has a separate, own disk. I will believe it when I see it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two hard drives, then installing Windows on one and Ubuntu (or any other OS) on the other is the most convenient.

1. most modern Windows PC's come with three partitions already installed - a recovery partition, the "System Reserved" partition, and finally your primary Windows partition. If only 3 Primary partitions are defined, create an extended partition and install Ubuntu there.
2. Assuming Windows consumes your entire first hard drive, then you must resize those Windows partitions.
3. There is a sense of security when installing the second OS on a separate hard drive. With two hard drives, you can just slip the primary one out (in the case of a laptop) or disconnect the power (for a desktop). Now you know that you are not going to accidentally corrupt your main OS while installing the other. For the truly paranoid, you can do the same when upgrading to newer versions.

E.g. My machine supports four hard drives; so I run Windows 7 on the primary and Ubuntu on the second. Rather than use the Linux boot loader to select my OS, I simply use the BIOS boot screen to choose to boot from the first or second hard drive. If I press the power button and walk away, then it boots from the primary disk unattended.

Ubuntu will be happy to mount your Windows partitions so that you can access your files.

Another option to consider is to use a virtual machine. I use VMware on my Windows partition  The only caveat is that you need enough memory and CPU power to run both OS's simultaneously.

One comment about redundancy - if you plan to set up any kind of disk redundancy (mirroring or RAID-5 striping) you need to have hard drives of close to the same size to avoid wasting space (the system will use the size of the smallest drive). A hardware approach is much more reliable and performs better than a simple software-based solution. You **MUST** back up any data you do not want to lose!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) For the future: please try to be concise: Although 32767 bytes *is* the maximum allowed, you're not writing dissertations here but are trying to help users with concise, precise information. (It's still too long now)

Answer (score 1):

From a strict system point of view, it is exactly the same ... provided you correctly configure your partitions. Correctly configured partitions are perfectly safe to use and you will never inadvertantly erase date in one partition while working on another one - be they under same OS or not.

If you configure them *by hand* hacking the Master Boot Record with low level tools ... it depends on your proficiency  with such tools ! But if you use high level tools to resize partitions and create next, you should not get into trouble.

As you asked for a safer way, my advice would be to split both disks with one Windows partition and one (or more) Ubuntu ones on each. That way, you could easily duplicate sensitive data on a second disk for any OS. You could even build a RAID-1 mirror for your (or one of your) Ubuntu partition(s). But I must admit it is a rather advanced configuration if you cannot afford (or do not want) to duplicate everything.

Comment: thanks. what does "split both disks with one Windows partition and one (or more) Ubuntu ones on each" mean?

Comment: @Tim It is common on Unix system to have more than one partition, a classical pattern is /, swap, /usr, /var and /home. But depending on usage, *your mileage may vary*. Typically, you could have 2 partitions (+ swap), one for data not needing mirroring (system and static data) and one for data deserving mirroring. For Windows, do as you want - after all we are here on a Unix site :-)

Comment: These days, with most software you will use being installed by distro packages, it doesn't make much sense to separate `/usr` from the root (`/`) filesystem.  Unless you like finding and reporting boot-ordering bugs.  Modern filesystems are quite good at aging well, so it's just a pain to divide up your space only to find that you have boatloads of space left on `/var`, but are running out of space on the root FS.  I like to put storage for multimedia stuff on a disk mounted on `/data` or w/e, rather than just in my home directory.

Comment: IMO, my home directory is for stuff I created or am working on, not just stuff I downloaded.  That way, I can more easily backup the stuff I care about, and ignore the stuff I could get from the Internet again.

Comment: @PeterCordes I generally use at least 2 partitions : one for the system (/ and /usr) and one for user files (/home). That way on a major version upgrade I just save config files (on home partition) and do a full install erasing everything on system partition(s) and keeping all on user partition. I put /var on system partition, put symlink on home partition folders that should survive to a reinstal (/var/www for example ...)

Comment: My current desktop has been continually upgraded from Ubuntu 6.10 or so to the current 14.10.  But I'm a Linux ninja and don't mind sorting out the occasional glitch.  Still, considering a re-install when moving to new disks, since I'm still on upstart, not the default-for-new-installs systemd, and probably some other things I don't know about.

Comment: But yeah, good to separate user-data from distro-data.  You still need to backup `/etc`, if you customize anything, though.  (and even better, version control it with `etckeeper`.)

Answer (score 1):

It would statistically be less safe to install onto two separate drives. If one drive fails you lose half of your data. Conversely, installing both OSs to one drive and keeping the (hypothetical?) second drive as a backup drive would give you a form of redundancy should one drive fail.

As far as your system is concerned, it doesn't matter if you partition one drive twice and install both operating systems there or install onto two separate drives.

Install both correctly and there is no danger of one OS wiping the other. You will likely need to grant access from each OS to the other if you want to share files between systems.

Comment: You could backup your windows stuff into a partition on the other drive, and vice versa.  So everything you care about is stored on both drives.  You might need a new drive and a live-boot USB stick to get your stuff again, depending on which drive you lose, but it'll be safe.  (remember, though, that RAID1 != backups, because it doesn't guard against accidental or other deletion.  It's very convenient, though.)

Comment: Yet I keep hearing about Windows updates messing up Linux bootloader partitions thus making same disk setup less safe